# Ionic 3 iOS release build failing

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to build(release) my ionic 3 apps for iOS. I was able to do it earlier without any problem but all of a sudden I started to get below errors

```
/Users/akash/Desktop/sourcecode /platforms/ios/Xpym/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/CDVWKWebViewEngine.h:21:9: fatal error: 'Cordova/CDV.h' file not found

#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
         CompileC /Users/akash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Xpym-bvfukasejehwgkcvbzmyfdzldbzg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Xpym.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Xpym.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/IONAssetHandler.o
/Users/akash/Desktop/sourcecode\
/platforms/ios/Xpym/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/IONAssetHandler.m
normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure) xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
```

I have tried removing `node_modules` folder and reinstalling them, reinstalling ios platform but I am now continuously getting this error.
But when I build it without --release, the build is successful.

Comment: What optimizations or other "differences" are setup for release builds (search paths, code optimizations, etc.)?

Comment: i have not setup anything extra , i am just using ionic cordova build ios --prod --release to get a release build

Comment: If I remember correctly, earlier versions of Cordova had an issue with the new build system in Xcode. You could try building with the legacy build system: `ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"` See also the related GitHub issue https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407